# Conditional Formating for Google Sheet comparing to list of text (highlight duplicates)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a custom formula for conditional formatting. I want to highlight the cell if the text appears in a list of names. This list will contain 210 unique names so I can't type each one of those into the formula. I am hoping I can reference a list, but can't seem to find a example for Google Sheets. I was able to see an example for excel that would reference a "List" you would create.

Thanks, 
Noel

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT** *(following your [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132793/conditional-formating-for-google-sheet-comparing-to-list-of-text/132795#comment121130_132795))*

**All duplicate values highlighted in both columns** is achieved using:

- In range `D3:D27`: `=COUNTIF($A$3:$A,D3)`
- In range `A3:A27`: `=COUNTIF($D$3:$D,A3)`

[image: duplicates in both columns.]

---

**First approach**

I believe the formula you need is as simple as:  `=$A1="Roman"`

[image]

Comment: Isn't that only looking for one answer of "Roman", but what if the list also had Bob, Kirk, Rebecca + all the rest? I want to highlight everyone that appears in a second list.

Comment: **Have you tried the updated solution offered?** Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)